Power BI Bacci's Gantt 2.0 - Center "Today" within viewport?
I am implementing project status reporting in Power BI using David Bacci's excellent "Gantt 2.0", which uses Vega in Deneb.  The solution to my first desired mod was found here (default to "Close" state rather than "Open") so I figured I'd try asking for the other I'd like to implement, which is to have the Gantt view center on Today's date, rather than always defaulting to the start of the project.
Any assistance is appreciated!
I have tried following the logic and making and testing changes, but to no avail.

Change xExt to the following:
{
  "name": "xExt",
  "update": "[today-oneDay,today+ ((ganttWidth-minDayBandwidth)/minDayBandwidth)*oneDay]"
},

This will do the initial load. You will probably need to make other changes for the other button grains if you're using them but the logic is the same.

Much appreciated!  And right from the creator too!  That moved "Today" to the start, rather than the center.  I added 30 ([today-oneDay30) and that seems to do the trick, but if there's a smarter way to do it, I'm all ears :)

You're welcome. Don't forget to mark as solved
